# How can I get an insufficient cpu error inside a GKE cluster with autopilot mode?

Tags: memory, google-kubernetes-engine, cpu

I created a cluster with autopilot mode. When I try to install an app inside this cluster using helm, workloads fail with this error `Does not have minimum availability`. If I click on this error, I get `Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu` and `Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient memory`.

If I do `kubectl describe node <name>` I find  `0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 3 Insufficient cpu`.

Isn't GKE autopilot mode supposed to allocate sufficient memory and cpu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where my mistake was. It had nothing to do with cpu or memomry. It was a mistake inside my yaml file (wrong host for database).